# save the temparay info in memory

Tags: python, python-2.7

there:
I tried to decompose the file names in a folder with '_' and I would like use these info 'lotID', 'operation', 'info' to match my input data. Here is my code:

```
import os
DES_DIR = 'source location'
name = str(raw_input('Please type Lot Number (XXXXXXXXX): '))
Op = int(raw_input('Please type Operation Number: '))
CD_job = str(raw_input('Please type info CD jobs:'))

for f in os.listdir(DES_DIR): 
    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)

    lotID = f_name.split('_')[1]

    operation =f_name.split('_')[2]

    info=f_name.split('_')[3]

    print lotID, operation, info
```

and this is what I got

```
a1 b1 c1
a2 b2 c2
a3 b3 c3
```

However, I relaize this is just a temp data in memory and I can't use them. How can I save them as a temporary file and reuse for next function? Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to store data in a file?

Comment: If you need them in another function that's part of the same script, you can make a function and return those values as a list of lists. Also in your current implementation you're performing `f_name.split` 3 separate times, which is probably unnecessary.

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
 result = (lotID, operation, info)
```

`result` become type `tuple`, to access your data do

```
lotID = result[0]
operation = result [1]
info = result[2]
```